# Remove an entity in a list of entities in another entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

I got an entity named Person and another one (Panel) which has a List of person in it.
The list of person is annoted by ManyToMany, because a person can be in several panels, and a panel can be composed of several persons. 
Is there any way to remove a person in the list of person if i delete a person from somewhere else ?

I'm not sure if i am clear enough. I looked at delete cascade, but i think it works this way : if i delete a panel, it will delete the persons in it, am i right ?

EDIT : here are the classes

```
public class Personne implements Serializable {

@Column(length=30)
private String nom;

@Column(length=30)
private String prenom;

@Column(length=40)  
private String emailCrypte;

@Id
@Column(length=30)
private String email;

@Column(length=30)
private String url_photo;

@Column(length=30)
private String plus_infos;

@Column
@ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
private List<String> organisations;

@Column(length=30)
private String homepage;

@Column
@ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
private List<String> id_reseaux_sociaux;}




public class Panel {

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="Panel_Auteurs",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Panel_titre", referencedColumnName="titre")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Auteurs_mail", referencedColumnName="email")})
private List<Personne> auteurs;

@Id
@Column(length=30)
private String titre;

@Column(length=30)
private String resume;

@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(name="Panel_MotsCles",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Panel_titre", referencedColumnName="titre")},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MotsCles_Desc", referencedColumnName="description")})
private List<MotCle> mots_cles;

@Column(length=30)
private String evenement;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="nom")
private Personne presentateur;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="Panel_Invites",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Panel_titre", referencedColumnName="titre")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Invites_mail", referencedColumnName="email")})
private List<Personne> invites;}
```

Comment: start by posting your classes, and the code where you delete a Person

Comment: Sure, i'll edit my question a few seconds, but the code will be in french though

Comment: By the way i do not have any code to delete a person yet, i wanted to ask first so i could create a delete code properly

Comment: What you are searching for is `orphanRemoval`.

Comment: You mean that if I use orphanRemoval on a delete form for Person, it will delete a person who is in the list of persons in my Panel class ? I'm gonna try it, thank you !

Comment: It seems that orphanRemoval isn't usable when you use ManyToMany. i can't use it without getting an error from Eclipse saying that orphanRemoval is undefined for manytomany